# For Excel, what does the keyboard shortcut "SP" mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

In excel, I'm trying to find a keyboard shortcut for the page setup.
From [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/shortcut-key-to-open-page-setup/ae5503db-6b52-4995-926b-eff51a532f34), it tells me that I should press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then the SP button.
For the "SP" I tried space and Windows Key but neither of them worked.

Does the "SP key" have a different meaning in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>P</kbd> in sequence.

Comment: That was the exact solution, thanks!